# GET from dynamic multidimensional form

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to GET all data from dynamic multidimensional form. Each column has different name and id like this :

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempselect");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2))
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($result2) ; $i++) { 
   echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0; $j < 12 ; $j++) { 
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" name=\"" . $i++ ."[]\"id=\"" .$row[$j] ."\" value=" . $row[$j] . "></td>";
         }
    }
}
```

Code above works properly, each column got different name and id. the output is like this :
[image]

The purpose from this form is to edit data from database and use it for next process. Now i want to combine all data into 1 multidimensional array like this :

```
2  4  4  .  .  . 0
3  .  .  .  .  . 0
3  .  .  .  .  . 0
.  .  .  .  .  . 0
.  .  .  .  .  . 0
3  .  .  .  .  . 0
```

I tried using code below, but only the first column saved into $data :

```
for ($i=0; $i <  count($_GET['0']); $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < count($_GET['submit_edit']); $j++) { 
        $data =$_GET[$j];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Should the array be grouped by column or by row?

Comment: @RobbieAverill hello, thank you for responding. The array should be grouped by column (example from image above C1 column name and id different with C2, etc.)

Comment: each row of your while loop  comes is overwriting  for loop  $i=0 again and again .i think this one is issue here

Comment: @jothi i think that's not the issue here, because code above and below located in a different php file. Thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $data = array();
    for ($i=0; $i <  count($_GET['0']); $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j < count($_GET['submit_edit']); $j++) { 
            $data[] =$_GET[$j];
        }
       }
```

This is just as you are doing i see $data has to be $data[] . However I dont know what rest you are doing. If this solves the problem then good, if doesnt then please make the question more clear related to $_GET['submit_edit'] and other $_GET's

Comment: Ah i see! it works! lol i feel so stupid right now! Thank you for your answer. it helps me alot! :D